# Flexible table with calculating column width fails starting from division by 10

Tags: tables

I received a table template, which I'm intended to generate dynamically with data using Java. But when the table becomes to large, the compilation with LaTeX fails. The specific about this template is, that it stretches the table width into the maximal page width and has same column widths for all data columns (except the first column).

Here is a minimal version of the full template, that still works fine:

```
\documentclass[final,authoryear,3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{fp}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\input{pgfexternal}

\newcommand\tabt{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}
\newcommand\tabb{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}L{2em}@{}*9{R{(\linewidth-2em)/9}@{}}}\hline\tabt
$i$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\tabb\tabularnewline\hline\tabt
$1$ &  & $48.87$ & $0.01$ & $0.05$ & $1.23$ & $0.00$ & $0.20$ & $5.67$ & $2.35$\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

But when extending this example by another column, so that the table would look like the following example, it fails:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}L{2em}@{}*10{R{(\linewidth-2em)/10}@{}}}\hline\tabt
$i$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$ & a\tabb\tabularnewline\hline\tabt
$1$ &  & $48.87$ & $0.01$ & $0.05$ & $1.23$ & $0.00$ & $0.20$ & $5.67$ & $2.35$ & b\tabularnewline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

This fails, no matter how many columns I add. So far, it seems for me to be a problem with the division by 10. May it be, that LaTeX isn't able to handle that properly by default? How can I solve this problem and make even larger tables work using this template. Or is that to any other problem I don't see yet? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `*10` is `*{1}0`  use `*{10}`

Comment: It's a common mistake in guides to teach `*3{...}` instead of the safer `*{3}{...}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*10` is `*{1}{0}`

so the `0` is taken as the column specifier repeated 1 time and generates

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (0): `c' used.
```

use `*{10}`

Since you are forcing the width anyway you could use `tabular` rather than `tabular*
which causes you to be a fraction under due to rounding error

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 24--27
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback. This solved the problem, but using tabular instead of tabular* doesn't work properly for me. It raises some error: ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\linewidth): `c'